# How to lock user using forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

Coding Platform: ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms with C#

I have two roles admin and member.
In my application, admin can manipulate most of the member data.
I know that in forms authentication a user can be unlocked like,

```
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(clickeduserName);
            user.UnlockUser();
            Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

My questions are,

1. How to lock a user in forms authentication?
2. Why is [`MembershipUser.IsLockedOut
   Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.islockedout.aspx) set as ReadOnly?
3. Is it not the right way to LockOut
   people as an administrator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options discussed here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1435151.aspx

They vary from using IsApproved (settable) instead of IsLockedOut to mucking with the underlying SQL database to set the lockout flag.

Answer (score 5):

You can make it lock the user (set `.IsLockedOut` to true) by doing the following:

```
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("UserToLock");        
    for (int i = 0; i < Membership.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts; i++)
    {
        Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, "Not the right password");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt from MSDN:

> Normally, User's are `LockedOut` automatically when the `MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts` is reached within the `PasswordAttemptWindow`.
>
> Users can also be locked out if you use the `GetPassword` or `ResetPassword` overload that accepts a password answer and the number of bad answers entered by the user reaches the value of Membership.`MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts` within the `Membership.PasswordAttemptWindow`.

A workaround could be to use IsApproved property like this:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
user.IsApproved = false;
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

Comment: @yetanothercoder .. i saw it later.. but it wasn't there before i commited my edit. :(

Comment: no probs :) and yeah.. i guess i have to go with !IsApproved.